# Spring Cloud Config with Spring Boot 1.4.5 - Precedence of encrypted properties

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-config

We have been using Spring Cloud Config for over 3 years now, and have well understood the order of precedence in Spring configuration properties between `bootstrap.yml`, `application.yml`, Test properties, environment variables, system properties and Spring profiles. At least that was the case until we ran into this issue today. We are using Spring Boot 1.4.5.

I have two properties defined in my `application.yml` as shown below:

`property:
  one: foobar
  two: "{cipher}s0m3encRypt3dv4lu3d0td0td0t"`

If I start my Spring Boot application and print the values of these two properties, I see the following - all as expected:

`property.one=foobar
property.two=DecryptedValue`

Now, if I try to override these two properties via the System properties (using `-D` option, or as a program argument with `--`), I see some interesting results:

`java -Dproperty.one=barfoo -Dproperty.two=WontWork -jar my-spring-boot-app.jar`

OR

`java -jar my-spring-boot-app.jar --property.one=barfoo -property.two=WontWork`

With this, when I print the properties in my app, I see the values as the following:

`property.one=barfoo
property.two=DecryptedValue`

As you can see, `property.one` is overridden as expected, but `property.two` does not; the latter picked the value from `application.yml`.

When I go to the /env endpoint of my Spring Boot app, I see that the `decrypted` properties are showing at the top of the list, making me think that *when I define an encrypted property, it's value in `application.yml`  always gets the precedence over any attempts to override the value of that property later*.

I could not find any references of this in Spring Cloud Config or Spring Boot documentation. If anyone can tell me if (1) this is a bug with a potential fix in later versions, and/or (2) there's a way to override this behavior.

Comment: I think it sounds similar to this issue - 
https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-config/issues/1013

Comment: Yes. Same issue, Indraneel.

Comment: they do monitor stack overflow questions but i think u should comment on that existing issue(don't create a new issue) .If , they feel its a common issue, it could be fixed in  a further release.